# Change affinity while process active

Tags: cpu, multi-threaded, affinity

I'm running a CPU consuming process (calculate mandelbrot set) and that process takes almost 100% of the CPU (I have 8 cores on my machine). when I change the affinity to half of the cores the CPU consumption show 50% or lower and that is cool but what I want to understand is how this magic is done:

**my question:**
If I change the affinity while the process is running and there are threads on disabled cores - Is it safe that I won't lose any data? how is it done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 8 CPU cores, but certainly there are more than 8 threads started. Just count all background processes - there are probably a few dozens of them, each having at least one thread. Operating system must deal with it somehow to provide real multitasking. So OS has a scheduler that starts, pauses and restarts threads according to some algorithm and some set of options. Affinity is one of such options, it determines on which cores the thread can be scheduled. Pausing and restarting threads happens all the time. So does moving them across cores (OS tries to schedule on the same cores, though, because it reduces frequency of cache misses and increases performance). It's safe.

Answer (score 3):

Although not specifically asked, I should point out (since I load all of my cores for weeks at a time, thus have some familiarity with this subject) that Affinity, while it can be useful, is not as important as Priority. Your jobs will generally finish twice as fast at 100%, compared to 50% CPU Utilization. Set the long running tasks to Low Priority and they will still run at 100% (as long as nothing of higher priority wants to run), but it will minimize the impact on doing other light-weight tasks. Only manage Affinity if there are fan noise/thermal issues you need to address... vacuuming my PC periodically gets me more mileage in that case.

Comment: I **strongly** second this. If the OP's motive is to keep their machine generally interactively usable while this CPU-intensive work is going on, lowering the process priority is the way to do it, rather than limiting affinity. I do this all the time for e.g. video rendering. As long as nothing of higher priority wants to run the Mandelbrot job will still get all of the CPU power. And even when something of higher priority does want to run the Mandelbrot job will be able to use whatever's CPU power is left.

Comment: In fact, to make this easier, i would suggest creating a little .cmd script that starts the Mandelbrot exe with the /low qualifier, to make it easier.

Answer (score 1):

It *shouldnt* have any affect on the program.  The operating system's scheduler will be notified that core is no longer available to be used. Switching a process from running state into a waiting state take microseconds, so the switch will appear instantaneous. The process will continue running on all available cores.

However, if the program was poorly written, or the compiler it was made from had some issues or bugs, the program could work improperly, or completely crash.

Comment: Is it correct to say that all relevant state/resources will move to the avilable cores? do you think that acting like that (reducing cores manually for CPU consumers that are not so important) is a good practice?

Comment: @yossico yes, everything *should* move.  However, "should" and "will" are not the same.  While I have changed the priority of a running task, its not something I would do unless it was absolutely necessary.  And I would not disable a core on a running process.  While it *should* work perfectly fine, I dont want to deal with the one time it doesnt.  If necessary I would set priorities and affinities *before* running the task.  Better to be safe than sorry, right?

Comment: @yossico I would test changing things first.  I wouldnt want to run a fractal generation program for 20 hours, then change a setting just to have it crash.  I would test to see what happens in the first few minutes, perhaps on a fractal that takes far less time.

Comment: I guess you are right, better safe than sorry... My fractals however runs for days... (when I generate a deep dive in 4K)

Comment: @Keltari Your concerns are unwarranted. Threads move between processors all the time. Windows even modifies thread priorities on the fly. Using affinity to shut a running program out of a processor is no different from the case when a higher-priority thread starts running there. Sure, if the program is poorly written or the compiler had bugs, those would cause problems, but the same problems could occur on any MP system even if the user wasn't twiddling affinity or priority.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely, positively, **no** risk of loss of data (or of data corruption) here. Or of process termination or any other problem. The windows scheduler handles this situation tens or even hundreds of times every second.

Changing process affinity (or changing its priority for that matter) - which really is changing the affinities (and priorities) of the process's threads - is just another reason for preemption.

After preemption, a thread may run on a different logical processor than it did the last time it was running. That is a completely common occurrence.